# Connection refused [tcp://IP-ADDRESS-HERE:6379] Redis. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, tcp, redis

I am trying to deploy laravel 5 app on shared hosting and it uses redis for caching. It displays error

> Connection refused [tcp://IP-ADDRESS-HERE:6379]

I have enabled Redis option in hosting, I am using php 5.4.

Comment: redis installed in that share hosting? you can access /etc/redis/redis.conf ?

Comment: Make sure the redis server is running by typing 'redis-server' on the command line

Comment: @ClearBoth Thank you for replying. I installed redis via composer. So it should be installed unless i have to install in a different way, and when i cd in /etc/redis i get No such file or directory

Comment: @RobFonseca Thank you for replying. When i type redis-server via ssh i get command not found

Comment: Redis doesn't install via composer. Sounds like you installed a library to interface with Redis.

Comment: Check out how to install it here http://redis.io/download . Predis is just a PHP library to work with Redis, not Redis itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I can't use port 6379 in the hosting company I'm with because they don't open that port for shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error trying to follow Laracast's socket.io course.

My steps to resolve this are in the comments above, but for clarity:

1. Run `brew install redis` (if on osx)
2. Run `redis-server`